# Jenkinsfile where are environment variables stored?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If I define environment variables in my Jenkinsfile https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/, where are they stored in the agent? I am specifically using Kubernetes plugin, and when I go into any of my containers and do `printenv` I don't see any of the environment variables I specified there. Where are they stored specifically? I am asking because I have a legacy Jenkinsfile that defined a lot of environment variables but it seems a lot of them are not used anymore, and I want to clean them up.

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins, when you define environment variables in a Jenkinsfile using the `environment` block, those variables are scoped to the Jenkins Pipeline job itself, and they are not directly stored in the agent's environment where you would see them with `printenv` or similar commands. These variables are specific to the Jenkins Pipeline runtime.

These environment variables are typically injected into the environment of the agent's processes spawned by the Jenkins Pipeline job during its execution. They are used to provide configuration or data to the job, but they won't be visible in a shell outside of the Jenkins Pipeline context.

Comment: So they are only useful to be used in the Jenkinsfile itself right? They can't be used implicitly by any program ran inside the file (e.g. a Python code run inside a stage cannot expect an environment variable defined here to be accessible)?

Comment: This is exactly how I understand it and this is how it works in my examples.

Please take a look at this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/ maybe it will help. (I haven't tested it)